# Using resources in converters

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to have a brush set to red or orange depending on some conditions, and to fallsback to the default brush if none of conditions are met.

If windows phone had style triggers this would be trivial, but as it doesn't, I have to create a special purpose converter for each scenario like this:

```
public class StatusToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var status = (Status)value;
        if (status.IsCancelled)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }
        else if (status.IsDelayed)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
        }
        else 
        {
            return parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Status, 
                                Converter={StaticResource statusToColorConverter},
                                ConverterParameter={StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}}" />
```

But now I need a converter that returns either `PhoneForegroundBrush` or `PhoneDisabledBrush` depending on a condition.

I can't pass two parameters, and MultiBindings aren't also supported in windows phone. I though of this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Status, 
                                Converter={StaticResource statusToColorConverter},
                                ConverterParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

So I could get the textblock in the parameter and then use it to lookup the resources, but it also doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean a condition other than the status value you're passing?

Comment: Could be the Status or anything else. The problem is that I need both that, and the brushes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare the brushes directly as properties on your converter:

```
public class StatusToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush CancelledBrush { get; set; }
    public Brush DelayedBrush { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var status = (Status)value;

        if (status.IsCancelled)
        {
            return this.CancelledBrush;
        }

        if (status.IsDelayed)
        {
            return this.DelayedBrush;
        }

        return parameter;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, fill them from the XAML when initializing the converter:

```
<my:StatusToColorConverter x:Key="StatusToColorConverter" CancelledBrush="{StaticResource CancelledBrush}" DelayedBrush="{StaticResource DelayedBrush}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, should have though of that